# Hello all. Can I install from an external cd player

Tags: boot, cd, drive

I am completely new to Ubuntu, and want to check it out, so I decided to install it momentarily along windows 7, on my Acer Extensa 5635z.

At first, I though of trying the windows installer and install it from Windows itself, but I can't find the installer on the website, so I'm currently downloading the iso file, which I will burn with imgburn.

However, the internal cd player of my laptop isn't working, and it's been taken out..it's currently at a friends house, as he wants to see if he can fix it.

In the meantime, I have an external Samsung CD/DVD player.

Will I be able to boot from that external cd player (I hope so)

If not, any alternative ideas?

Comment: You will probably have to set your bios to be able to boot from it. As long as your bios allows it, it will be possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: This link may help http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you set your bios to boot from it you probably can but it's probably easier to install ubuntu from a flash drive.
To do this you'll need your iso that you are currently downloading and a program called [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and of course a flash drive of minimal 1 gb.

Next up is making the usb bootable. This can be done by the following steps:
1) insert your usb.
2) run UNetBootin
3) select the "diskimage" radio button (see picture)
4) select your iso file
5) select your usb drive 
6) press ok

After this the usb will become a bootable usb and you can install linux using this usb.

[image: What to do]
[image: loading]

pictures are from the UNetBootin website